# Selecting array elements using a binary pattern as the selector

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, binary, nsarray

I have an `NSArray`, and I've calculated a list of integers that represent (in binary) the elements I need to pull out of the array into a new array.

For example, I have 7, 11, and 13, whose bit patterns are `000111`, `001011`, and `001101`. I want to grab three arrays, made of elements 0,1,2, then elements 0,1,3, and then 0,2,3 out of the main array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct an `NSIndexSet` from the bit patterns you have:

```
@implementation NSIndexSet (NonContiguous)
+ (instancetype)indexSetFromMask:(NSUInteger)mask
{
    NSMutableIndexSet * set = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

    for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < (sizeof(NSUInteger) * 8); i++ ){
        if( mask & (1l << i) ){
            [set addIndex:i];
        }
    }

    return set;
}
@end
```

Then use `objectsAtIndexes:`

```
[origArray objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetFromMask:7]];
// etc.
```

Comment: for some reason, this code is only returning the 1st four elements properly. If the numbers are larger than 15, all of the upper columns are discarded. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep, that's what happens when you post code on SO without running it or even re-reading it. `sizeof()` is the number of bytes, not bits, so the loop terminator needs to be `i < (sizeof(NSUInteger) * 8)`. The `1` in the mask test also needs to be `1l` when NSUInteger is 64 bits. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the output to be in the form [[a,b,c],[a,b,d],[a,c,d]] for the example, you could do something like this:

```
NSArray *sourceArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",...,nil];
NSArray *grabArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11],[NSNumber numberWithInt:13],...,nil];
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then for each element of grabArray, add the correct elements to resultArray:

```
for (NSNumber num in grabArray) {
    int n = [num intValue];
    int bit = floor(log2(n)); //get highest bit in the current number
    NSMutableArray *curr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    while (n>0) {
        if (n>pow(bit,2)) { //if this bit is a 1
            [curr addObject:[sourceArray objectAtIndex:bit]];
        }
        n-=pow(bit,2);
        bit-=1;
    }
    [resultArray addObject:curr];
}
```

Then resultArray should be the array you are looking for. It will add the objects in reverse order, so if order matters you would want to use `[curr insertObject: [sourceArray objectAtIndex:bit] atIndex:0];` instead.

Comment: This was returning a large number of out-of-bounds indexes and it does not seem to catch all of the correct bits.